# How can I get result format JSON from Athena in AWS?

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena

I want to get result value format JSON from Athena in AWS.

When I select from the Athena then the result format like this.

```
{test.value={report_1=test, report_2=normal, report_3=hard}}
```

Is there any way to get JSON format result without replacing "=" to ":" ?

The column format is

```
map<string,map<string,string>>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select  mycol
from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            mycol                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| {test.value={report_3=hard, report_2=normal, report_1=test}} |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
select  cast (mycol as json) as json
from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   json                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"test.value":{"report_1":"test","report_2":"normal","report_3":"hard"}} |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question. When the data mixed with string and map data then can I make string data to json format also?

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, when i do "select mycol" its giving response like you are getting i,e {k1= v1, k2=v2, k3=v3} 
and when i do "select  cast (mycol as json) as json" its giving response like ["v1","v2","v3"] without the keys
My underlying schema is Avro and stored in parquet format.

Comment: Please follow SO guidelines and post a new question for this. **(1)** Avro and Parquet are 2 different unrelated storage formats **(2)** You'll need to provide your column schema.

Answer (score 0):

If your input format is json (i.e. your whole row is JSON) you can create a new table that holds athena results in whatever format you specify out of several possible options like parquet, json, orc etc. This would ultimately end up storing all athena results of your query, in an s3 bucket with the desired format.

hope this helps

here's the documentation for reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html