# aws athena query result in json format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I create aws athena table that contain some rows

example of data:

```
first_name | age
=================
    a         20
    b         30
    c         35
```

When I query the data I the result are saved in CSV format in S3.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

I would query the data and get the result in JSON format.

The reason is that I should transfer that JSON data to another application for another process.

Is there a way to get query result in JSON format?

Comment: Have you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128172/how-can-i-get-result-format-json-from-athena-in-aws)?

Comment: @Marcin sure,
When call : ```SELECT cast (first_name AS json) AS json, cast (age AS json) AS json1 from table1```

It just converts the name from a to "a", but stll in csv format

Comment: Athena only returns a .csv file as a result, if you want to pass this result to a json, look for an alternative by using the services of GLUE or LAMBDA for example to use a python or SCALA library that allows you to transform the output format of this result .